# Stream Analytics doesn't output the data to SQL but does to a blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

In my project I receive data from Azure IoThub and want to send it to a SQL database using Azure stream analytics. I'm trying to achieve this using the following query:

```
SELECT
    IoTDataArrayElement.ArrayValue.sProjectID AS id
INTO
    [test-machine]
FROM
    [iothub-input] AS e
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(e.iotdata) AS IoTDataArrayElement
HAVING IoTDataArrayElement.ArrayValue IS NOT NULL
```

When I run the query in the environment provided by stream analytics and press test query I get the expected output which is a projectID. But when I start the stream analytics job the data doesn't go in to my database table. The table has 1 column 'id'.

When I try to send all the data to a blob storage the stream analytics job works.

Can someone please explain to me why the query I use for sending the data to a database doesn't actually send the data to a database?

Comment: is the column type in the database compatible? Does the db firewall allow connections from ASA?

Comment: @silent Thanks for the comment, The db does allow connections from ASA and the columnh type in the database is compatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things you need to verify to make successfully configuration of  Azure SQL DB as output:

- Make sure firewall settings is ON for All Azure Services.

[image]

- Make sure you have configured the output to the sql database with the correct properties defined.

The following table lists the property names and their description for creating a SQL Database output.

[image]

- Make sure the table schema must exactly match the fields and their
  types in your job's output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found out that it is hard to store data from asa to a relational database. So i decided to write a azure function wich i now use as a output. The functions takes care of the data and de placements in the correct tables.

Comment: @Collin Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?